# How to define a variable from controller inside app.js in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to open pages only when login is successful,
I used flag in controller which I want to show in app.js as well.

headerCtrl.js:

```
$scope.verifyOTP = function(mobileNumber,otpNumber) {
   $rootScope.UserAuthorised=false;
   $http.get($scope.url,config).success(function(data, status) {
       $rootScope.UserAuthorised=true;
       $window.alert("Login Successfully!! ");
       var Mypath = '/home' ;
       $location.path(Mypath); 
       $location.replace();  
   })
}
```

App.js:

```
if($rootScope.UserAuthorised==true){
    adminApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/credentials/registration.html',
            controller  : ''
        })  
    })
}
```

How do I define my variable in from controller into app.js so that i can change my flag from true to false and vice versa.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are trying to achieve... if it is authenticating client use the `resolve` property in your routing config...

Answer (score 0):

> headerCtrl.js

```
$scope.UserAuthorised=true; //remove this line and replace with following line
localStorage.setItem("UserAuthorised", "true");
```

> App.js

```
$routeProvider.when('/secure', {templateUrl: '/secure.html', controller: 'Secure',resolve:{loggedIn:onlyLoggedIn}});

        var onlyLoggedIn = function ($location,$q) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var isLogin = localStorage.getItem("UserAuthorised");
            if (isLogin == 'true') {
                deferred.resolve();
            } else {
                deferred.reject();
                $location.url('/login');
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        };
```

Comment: what if I have multiple pages to show after login and also in your code user can still go ' /home ' by typing address in browser.

Answer (score 0):

> HeaderCtrl.js

`$rootScope.UserAuthorised=true;`

> App.js

```
adminApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/home', {
        templateUrl : function($rootScope){
            if ($rootScope.UserAuthorised){
                  return  'pages/credentials/registration.html';
                  }
                  else return '/login.html';
        }
        controller  : ''
    })  
})
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that, you can use $window.sessionStorage, $rootScope as mentioned above and if possible use Service when dealing with controllers before you change your state/location.